# The measurement and causality?

Tags: metaphysics, quantum-physics

So my question is how do we establish that the measuring device causes the measurement (/collapse of the wave function)?

Is it as crude as my experimentalist friend told me so and won the best each time? Or have me managed to make better progress?

From Stanford encyclopedia of philosophy:

> If quantum theory is meant to be (in principle) a universal theory, it
> should be applicable, in principle, to all physical systems, including
> systems as large and complicated as our experimental apparatus. It is
> easy to show that linear evolution of quantum states, when applied to
> macroscopic objects, will routinely lead to superpositions of
> macroscopically distinct states. Among the circumstances in which this
> will happen are experimental set-ups, and much of the early
> discussions focussed on how to construe the process of measurement in
> quantum-mechanical terms. For this reason, the interpretational issues
> have come to be referred to as the measurement problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly is it about measurements that you don't understand? A measuring device patently produces a measurement, so your question doesn't make sense when taken literally.

Comment: So usually to argue causation you think of think of initial value problems. So now at some point during the time evolution we define a cut off and say the measurement has happened! (The further evolution is given by the born rule). Given that it's an open problem on when this cuttoff is invoked how does make the statment: the measuring devices caused the measurement

Comment: In the example I give below, there isn't an arbitrary 'cut-off'. There is a very definite interaction between an electron and a photographic plate.

Comment: Pop physics is not physics. Collapse is an interpretation, not a fact of nature.

Comment: @user4894 unfortunately to make the question i have to commit to some framework. Also Schrodingers cat was both dead and alive until i opened the box and measured it. Why couldn't the cat make a measurement on itself, etc i don't kno

Comment: I understand nothing in quantum physics but it looks similar like Akutagawa's story "In a Grove", where observer's views change causes of the narrative.
Cat was inside the box and can't measure itself without connecting with  outside observer. All that we know about the cat an observer's version or his measure tools, cat was mewless it slept or same.

Comment: The fact that you think Schrödinger's cat was dead and alive suggest to me that you are a victim of pop physics. Schrodinger proposed that thought experiment to underline how ludicrous it was to suppose the cat was both dead and alive, yet today everyone takes it to be true!

Comment: @MarcoOcram i know the historical background. You can see wigners friend extended version. These type of thought experiments are far from settled in Quantum information.

Comment: Indeed, and my message to you is that such questions arise because people treat the simplified models of QM as if they were reality. As for Eugene Wigner, he was one of the instigators of the 'consciousness causes collapse' meme, a nonsensical conflation of a phenomenon we don't understand with a phenomenon we have imagined.

Comment: @MarcoOcram wigners friend extended version is different from WIgner's friend. See this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6143649/ This have gone far beyond the historical backlog you keep mentioning

Answer (score 2):

The measurement problem in quantum mechanics refers to the difficulties in understanding how the measurement of a quantum system leads to the collapse of the wave function and the transition from a superposition of states to a definite state. The idea that the measurement device causes the measurement is based on the interaction between the quantum system and the device, which leads to the transfer of information from the system to the device. This interaction can be modeled using quantum mechanics and it is through this interaction that the wave function of the quantum system collapses to a definite state.
While there have been various proposals to solve the measurement problem, including the Copenhagen interpretation, the many-worlds interpretation, and the spontaneous collapse theories, no single interpretation has gained universal acceptance. In general, the progress in resolving the measurement problem has been limited by the difficulty of making predictions about the behavior of macroscopic objects within the framework of quantum mechanics. However, the study of the measurement problem remains an active area of research, and there have been many recent advances in our understanding of quantum systems and their interactions with the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Take a very basic example. You fire an electron towards a barrier with two slits, beyond which is a photographic plate. Later, when you develop the plate you find a bright spot where the electron has hit. If you like, you can repeat the experiment, but this time you fire ten thousand electron through, one at a time, each with the same energy, more or less. When you now develop the plate, you see ten thousand spots which together form a diffraction pattern.  Each spot is a 'measurement' of the position at which an electron impinged upon the photographic plate. The spacing between the bright or dark lines in the diffraction pattern is an indication, or 'measurement' if you like, of the wavelength of the electrons. What 'causes' the observed bright spots? The interaction of individual electrons with the chemicals on the plate. What 'causes' the diffraction pattern? The fact that the electrons have passed through two slits. What 'caused' the electrons to do those things? The fact that a scientist rigged up an experiment to make it happen. If you would like to pinpoint which aspect of that description is unsatisfactory, I will extend my answer accordingly.

ADDENDUM

When discussing the so called  measurement problem, you need to bear in mind that the main equation of quantum mechanics- the Schrodinger equation- is impossible to solve for anything but the most trivial case, and as a consequence of that, physicists make drastically simplifying assumptions when performing calculations. For example, when calculating energy levels in solids, its usual to adopt the 'single electron' model, in which you solve the equation by modelling the countless trillions of interactions between the particles in the solid as if there was just one electron and the effects of all the others are averaged out and represented as a classical background potential. If you consider the 'two slits' experiment I described above, why happens is towards the end of the experiment an electron passing through the apparatus leaves a region in which its behaviour can be modelled as though it was in free space and enters a region in which that assumption no longer holds, ie a region in which there are countless trillions of other charged particles forming the photographic plate. We summarise that as the electron's free-space wave function 'collapsing' when it meets the plate, but of course that is a sweeping simplification. What 'really' happens is that the electron's behaviour is influenced by an extremely complicated and time-dependent potential, and if we could properly model that we wouldn't need to talk about collapse- instead we could solve the Schrodinger equation for the electron and all the other particles of the apparatus to determine a multi-particle wavefunction that evolves in a particular way. Collapse is a shorthand for saying that the wave function we have supposed as a consequence of our simple model can no longer be correct beyond a certain point, where a different model wave-function needs to be supposed.

Comment: You start with: " What 'causes' the observed bright spots? The interaction of individual electrons with the chemicals on the plate." go through an addendum of: ". What 'really' happens is that the electron's behaviour is influenced by an extremely complicated and time-dependent potential, and if we could properly model that we wouldn't need to talk about collapse- instead we could solve the Schrodinger equation for the electron and all the other particles of the apparatus to determine a multi-particle wavefunction that evolves in a particular way."

Comment: and end with "Collapse is a shorthand for saying that the wave function we have supposed as a consequence of our simple model can no longer be correct beyond a certain point, where a different model wave-function needs to be supposed."

Comment: I'm not sure what the final take away is suppose to be. But I dont think any amount of complicated interaction can defy unitarity.

Comment: The intended take away was that the 'collapse' of the wavefunction is probably just an artefact of our highly simplified mathematical modelling, so don't waste your time pondering questions that pre-suppose it is  anything else.

Comment: I don't see then how one can't argue that the interaction with the wall as a causative element is a simplified artefact either?

Comment: No it isn't- the simplification is that we treat the wall as a classical barrier- we don't model the individual interactions between the electron and the particles that comprise the apparatus, because that's just impossibly hard to do.

Comment: " I dont think any amount of complicated interaction can defy unitarity" this remains to be answered and it sounds like you are relying more on intuition (not that that's a bad thing) rather than a framework

Comment: @MoreAnonymous What does "any amount of complicated interaction can defy unitarity" actually mean? "Unitarity" in QM refers to a specific property of the operators we use to model observables (the inverse is the conjugate transpose). Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: The transformation of a state vector when it undergoes the measurement process is not unitary

Comment: The non-unitary nature is an artefact of the model.

Comment: @MoreAnonymous I see - well, so be it. The thing is, all those questions eventually have to be settled by _experiments_, not any opinion or speculation.

Comment: @Frank i do agree experiment plays a role but what sort of experimental data do we need that we don't already have?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Need to answer what question exactly?